# Resizing an image in % does not change the width of the parent container

Tags: html, css

With this HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="">
        <img id="logo" src="logo.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Let's say `#logo`'s width is 100px. If I resize the image in percentage:

```
#logo {
    width: 10%;
}
```

`#logo`'s width has changed to `10px`, but `#navbar-header` is still at `100px`. If I set the image's width in pixels I don't have this problem.

How can I resize an image's width and also have it's parent container resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the size of your logo in `px` and don't specify a size of it's parent the parent will get the size of it's content. But when you set logo's size in `%` this percent should be calculated of some value and since it's parent don't have a specified width it's trying to rely on something, in this case there's only logo's native image width to rely on. In this way the parent will get a size of original logo's width and then logo will get calculated percent of it's parent size.

I can see 3 different ways to solve your problem:

1. Put your logo without a div and set `display:block` for it
2. May be in your particular case you can use `vw` units instead of `px` or `%`
3. Use some javascript solution

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! And you're right, when using `vw` or `vh` the problem goes away. Since the bootstrap navbar never changes height, I think I'll just resort to using `px`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The key solution to your problem is to use **display:inline-block;**

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Camaupoint">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-header
{
  display:inline-block;
}
#logo 
{
  width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` on `.navbar-header` has no effect. You're suggesting this because you want the `.navbar-header`'s width to fit it's content's width, but it's already doing that. The problem is that it's fitting the content's width **before the image has been resized**. Essentially `.navbar-header` is ignoring the fact that the image has been resized. @Cheslab might be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline block on the container like someone said

or you could make the img 100% and the container box the size you want

```
.navbar-header {
    width: 10%
}

#logo {
    width: 100%;
}
```